# unable to connect to kafka broker (via zookeeper) using Conduktor client

Tags: apache-kafka, conduktor

Able to connect successfully to local kafka broker/cluster running locally (dockerized) using Conduktor, but when trying to connect to Kafka cluster running on Unix VM, getting below error.
**Error:**
"The broker [...] is reachable but Kafka can't connect. Ensure you have access to the *advertised listeners* of the the brokers and the proper authorization"

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

> running locally (dockerized)

When running in docker, you need to ensure that the ports are accessible from outside of your container. To verify this, try doing a `telnet <ip> <port>` and check if you are able to connect.

Since the error message says, the broker is reachable, I suppose you would be able to successfully `telnet` to the broker.

Next, check your broker config called `advertised.listeners`. Here you need to mention your `IP`:`Port` combination where `IP` is what you will be giving in your client program i.e. Conduktor.

An example for that would be

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://1.2.3.4:9092
```

and then restart your broker and reconnect. If you are using `ssl` then you need to provide some extra configuration. See [Configuring Kafka brokers](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.1/kafka-securing/topics/kafka-secure-tls-broker.html) for more.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add in /etc/hosts (Unix-like) or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts (windows-like) the Kafka server in such manner kafka_server_ip kafka_server_name_in_dns (e.g. 10.10.0.1 kafka).